# Function call ending with [0][0]

Tags: javascript

```
var sensor = _this.createSensor("svg", mouse, "sensor_" + timestamp.substring(2, timestamp.length - 2))[0][0];
```

**Can someone tell me what the [0][0] at the end of the function call is for?**

Here is the header of my function :

```
DragSensorController.prototype.createSensor = function (parent, startPoint, id, ip, typeid, timestamp) {
```

Comment: A 2D array access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that:

```
_this.createSensor("svg", mouse, "sensor_" + timestamp.substring(2, timestamp.length - 2))
```

Returns an array of an array like:

```
[['foo']]
```

To access it, you need to use the `[0][0]`.

```js
const data = [['foo']];

console.log(data[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `createSensor` functions probably returns an array of arrays. For example:

`[['item1', 'item2'], ['something1']]`

So essentially it is selecting the first item from the first array. In this case `item1`

Answer (score 1):

It means that the function returns an array and the first `[0]` obtains a reference to the first array element. Then, that element is, itself an array, so the second `[0]` gets the first element of that array.

```js
function foo(){
  var a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
  
  // Calling this function will return an array consisting of two arrays
  return a;
}

// Run the function and get the first item from the first array
console.log(foo()[0][0]);  // 1

// Run the function and get the 3rd item from the second array
console.log(foo()[1][2]);  // 6
```

Comment: It might be more correct to say an array-like object, perhaps.

Comment: @Amy We don't really know, but for the purpose of this question, it doesn't matter.